# Doctrine Mongo ODM merge for externally modified data

Tags: rest, doctrine-odm, symfony-2.1

I'm writing a Symfony2 app that allows mobile users to create and update "Homes" via a REST service. I'm using MongoDB as the storage layer and Doctrine MongoDB ODM to do the Document handling.

The `GET /homes/{key}` and `POST /homes` methods are working fine. The problem comes when I attempt to update an existing Home with `PUT /homes/{key}`.

Here's the current code:

```php
/**
 * PUT /homes/{key}
 *
 * Updates an existing Home.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param string $key
 * @return Response
 * @throws HttpException
 */
public function putHomeAction(Request $request, $key)
{
    // check that the home exists
    $home = $this->getRepository()->findOneBy(array('key' => (int) $key));

    // disallow create via PUT as we want to generate key ourselves
    if (!$home) {
        throw new HttpException(403, 'Home key: '.$key." doesn't exist, to create use POST /homes");
    }

    // create object graph from JSON string
    $updatedHome = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize(
        $request->getContent(), 'Acme\ApiBundle\Document\Home', 'json'
    );

    // replace existing Home with new data
    $dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
    $home = $dm->merge($updatedHome);
    $dm->flush();

    $view = View::create()
        ->setStatusCode(200)
        ->setData($home);

    $response = $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
    $response->setETag(md5($response->getContent()));
    $response->setLastModified($home->getUpdated());

    return $response;
}
```

The JSON string passed to the action is successfully deserialized to my Document object graph by JMSSerializer, but when I attempt the merge & flush, I get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index:  in ..../vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php line 1265
```

I've been attempting to follow the documentation here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-documents

Is there something I need to do to the deserialized Home before attempting to merge it? Is merge the wrong method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to do this is to create a method in your document class that takes the updated document (e.g. `$updatedHome`) as a parameter and then just copies the required fields over into the existing document (e.g. `$home`).

So above, the code:

```
// replace existing Home with new data
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$home = $dm->merge($updatedHome);
$dm->flush();
```

can be replaced with:

```
// replace existing Home with new data
$home->copyFromSibling($updatedHome);
$this->getDocumentManager()->flush();
```

and then it will work.